# How to cancel ONE item using amazon mws order adjustment feed?

Tags: amazon-mws

I've been trying to cancel single item from an amazon order using their order adjustment feed, but every time I submit request I get:

> ERROR 18028: The data you submitted with this item is incomplete or invalid. Please resubmit the item with all required fields completed with valid data.

I've used this xml in my requests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderAdjustment</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <OrderAdjustment>
        <AmazonOrderID>305-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX</AmazonOrderID>
        <ActionType>Cancel</ActionType>
        <AdjustedItem>
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>209XXXXXXXXXXX</AmazonOrderItemCode>
            <AdjustmentReason>NoInventory</AdjustmentReason>
            <QuantityCancelled>1</QuantityCancelled>
        </AdjustedItem>
    </OrderAdjustment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I have double checked my xml and it seems to be valid according to amazon's xsd schema.

I would appreciate if someone with similar problem could share their experience.

Comment: have you looked at the SC forums? https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/search?q=order%20adjustment%20feed

Comment: I've browsed SC forums, but I am not able to find answer to this particular problem.

Comment: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html  They can lookup your requests and give you more info

Comment: Also tried that and after several open cases all I got from them is that "I am not sending something that they need so I should re-submit the feed with corrected information aligned with XSD..." Nobody can tell me what information and my XML is based on their XSD. I tried sending invalid XML just to test it and with that I get proper response saying XML is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Try setting the ActionType to **Refund** instead of **Cancel**.

**This concerns merchant that do their own fulfillment.**

Two scenarios come to mind, an order with:

1. two items, each with quantity 1
2. one item with quantity 2

Logically, a partial cancel involves fulfilling one item and canceling the second.

Since the MWS API does not have a single operation for a partial cancel, the application has to first fulfill the second item and then refund it.

That means first sending an OrderFulfillment message for the second item and then sending an OrderAdjustment for it.

I've found that the ActionType of Cancel gives the same error message as seen in the original post while a value of Refund is successfully processed.